# Profiling not working in Eclipse CDT Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) on Linux

Tags: eclipse, profiling, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse CDT Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) installed on Ubuntu 18.04.  The "perf" binary is installed.  When I try to profile a simple CDT C++ application, I see no output in the "Perf profile view" tab, and the console output tab displays this:

```
failed to open perf.data : Permission denied
Perf session creation failed.
/usr/bin/perf record --output=perf.data /home/smachin/eclipse-workspace/seanlabs/Debug/seanlabs 
Analysing recorded perf.data, please wait...
ERROR: Unable to find Perf version, please verify it is installed and on the run path
```

How do I get profiling working?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in CDT 2019 12

Comment: Well the error message does at least indicate that running Eclipse with `sudo` is a workaround. I tried this and it seems to work. Still annoying though.

Comment: NOTE: This may require the use of `chown` to run Eclipse without `sudo` again.

Comment: Also, with kernel version 5, I found that I had to install the `linux-tools-generic-5*` package for my specific kernel version before it worked. *Checking the existence of `/usr/bin/perf` is not sufficient.* Run `/usr/bin/perf --version` to check if perf was installed successfully.